# TabControl - How to force event OnGetImageIndex

Tags: delphi, tabcontrol, vcl

I have a Delphi VCL form application (for Windows) with a TabControl component, where tabs are created at run time. `Images` property is linked to a ImageList, and I am using the OnGetImageIndex event to set the image index for each tab, based on a status information. At certain point, when status change, I need to update this images (indexes). My first idea is to call:

```
TabControl1.Invalidate;
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried another approachs without success:

```
TabControl1.Repaint;

RedrawWindow(TabControl1.Handle, nil, 0, RDW_ERASE or
  RDW_INVALIDATE or RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
```

Please, how can I force OnGetImageIndex for each tab? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the protected [`UpdateTabImages`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTabControl.UpdateTabImages) method which sends a [`TCM_SETITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tcm-setitem) for each tab.

```
type
  TAccessTabControl = class(TTabControl);

...

  TAccessTabControl(TabControl1).UpdateTabImages;
```

Comment: Great solution! Thank you!